# Samsung I5503 weak Wi-Fi

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-5

Me and my friend's galaxy 5 has a weak Wi-Fi signal. Even in a few meters from access point, it has 2 lines of antenna.
Is there any solution for increasing signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes there may be interference from other electronic / microwave equipment.

In your router / access point's settings change the channel and see if there's any improvement.

Also, don't be taken in so much by the bars displayed. Very often, I see only 2 bars, but in the WiFi settings, I see the signal strength displayed as EXCELLENT.

The other usual rules apply - place your router as high as you can. Place it away from other cordless phones or electronic devices that can generate interference.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tested it by 5 or 6 access points. If the distance is above 10 meters, it disconnects frequently. But I should test channels.